# JQuery .load() callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, load

I've seen lots of questions and solutions to problems like this but nothing has worked for me. I have this:

```
function() {
    $("#bdiv").load("bosses.php #icc10n",function(){
        return $("#bdiv").html();
    });
}
```

But it's not working. To clarify, I want to load content into `#bdiv` and then return the contents of `#bdiv`. But it seems that `$("#bdiv").html()` is being returned before the content is loaded even though I've put it in a callback function.

Comment: Can you show the full code? Why is this in an anonymous function?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
$("#bdiv").load("bosses.php #icc10n",function(data){
    // use the data param
    // e.g. $(data).find('#icc10n')
});
```

Answer (score 1):

as far as I know you cannot make a **return** statement in the callback function of a $.ajax(), $.post(), $.get(), etc.. method. You could, however, store the 'data' value in a variable declared outside the function, and then set the value of that variable when the callback function executes. And there is a variety of other options.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that.

AJAX is *asynchronous*, meaning that your function will return before the server sends a response.
You need to pass the value to your caller using a callback, the way `$.load` does.

Comment: @Onkelborg: He needs to return the value by making his own callback.

Comment: The .html() is evaluated when the function is declared, and not when it's called, right?

Comment: @Santiago: Totally wrong.  The `return` statement is returning from the inner callback method; this return value is ignored by jQuery.  The outer function returns immediately.

Comment: Call me slow, but I still don't really understand how it's done and why the above approach doesn't work. I know this is not my question, but would you mind adding an example and/or explaining a bit further? This bit my curiosity!