# How to use .load function inside a .wrap function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-load

I want to wrap content retrieved with load in jQuery, but I am not sure of the correct syntax, or possibly it's not possible to combine the two this way.

This is throwing an Uncaught TypeError:

```
$('video').wrap(function(){
        $.load('videoholder.php');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the wrap in a callback (after the AJAX response comes back).

See: [JQuery .load() callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973933/jquery-load-callback-function)

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not the correct syntax.

```
$('video').load('videoholder.php')
```

Answer (score 0):

What Diodeus said. Try this:

```
$.load('videoholder.php', function(response, status, xhr) {
    $('video').wrap(response);
})
```

Comment: that's throwing the same error. think I have to load the php into something initially?

Comment: First idea: make sure jQuery is loading properly. Second idea: Exactly what code is your videoholder.php script returning? It should be a valid HTML snippet that works with wrap(). http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Answer (score -1):

> Use the callback in the load function and wrap the returned data.
>   Some rough code below.

```
$.load('videoholder.php', function( data ){ 
   $('video').wrap( data ); 
})
```

;

Comment: What is videoholder.php returning ? If it's returning html this should work fine. What kind of error do you get ?