# Add loading progress for .load()

Tags: jquery

I want to ask is that any good AJAX jQuery code for `.load()`

I am using `.load()` method to call over other file into certain div id by `onclick="myfunction()"` and it always need to hold awhile for progress.

Now what i want to do is how to add something while the progress, for better performance.

Any ideal guy ^^

before that thx for read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the ajaxSend and ajaxComplete methods. Further reading: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSend/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the callback on `.load()` see [JQuery .load() callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973933/jquery-load-callback-function).
Then simply display the loading animation before you call .load() and then hide it in the callback.

A real progress bar with percentage is a bit more cumbersome.